# How can I know how many concurrent flows are currently active

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

Does Spring-WebFlow provide a way of getting to know the number of flows currently executing ?

I could work around it with a global bean, but maybe WebFlow provides a solution out-of-the-box.

**Edit:** As requested, here the so called "Global Bean" solution based on a 
[FlowExecutionListenerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/FlowExecutionListenerAdapter.html)

```
package your.package;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.AttributeMap;
import org.springframework.webflow.definition.StateDefinition;
import org.springframework.webflow.definition.TransitionDefinition;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowSession;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext;

public class FlowExecutionListener extends FlowExecutionListenerAdapter {

    private static Logger   logger          = Logger.getLogger(FlowExecutionListener.class);
    private int             sessionCount    = 0;


    @Override
    public void sessionStarted(final RequestContext context, final FlowSession session) {
        super.sessionStarted(context, session);
        sessionCount++;
        logger.debug("sessionStarted, state: " + session.getState().getId() + ", count: " + sessionCount);
    }


    @Override
    public void sessionEnded(final RequestContext context, final FlowSession session, final String outcome, final AttributeMap output) {
        super.sessionEnded(context, session, outcome, output);
        sessionCount--;
        logger.debug("sessionEnded, state: " + session.getState().getId() + ", count: " + sessionCount);
    }

}
```

The bean must be registered at Spring-level:

```
<bean id="flowExecutionListener" class="your.package.FlowExecutionListener" />
```

**Edit2:**

If you have more than one WebFlow in your application, this would count **all** the active flows. In case you want to account them separately, you can get the flow's ID with *session.getDefinition().getId()*.

Comment: could you post your "global bean" solution?